# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient : 530 Please login with USER and PASS

Tags: java, ftp-client

I want to visit a FTP server and get a directory list from the ftp server.So I use org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient to complete it. But the ftp server donn't need to login .so my code is like this

```
ftpClient.connect(ip, port);
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(timePath);
FTPFile[] directoryArray = ftpClient.listFiles();
```

when I debug it ,there is no any error and exception. But I get nothing,then i find thisreplylines size = 1 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
the FTP server doesn't have user and password to login.how can i solve it？ thanks

Comment: It look like it requres authorization after all. How do you know that 'the FTP server doesn't have user and password to login'?

Comment: Please try username: "anonymous" and anything for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging in as anonymous ("anonymous" is the default user in many FTP servers):

```
ftpClient.connect(ip, port);
ftpClient.login("anonymous", "");
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(timePath);
FTPFile[] directoryArray = ftpClient.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit username and password parameters like this:

```
username = "anonymous";
password = System.getProperty("user.name")+"@"+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

[Source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java)

Comment: How? By assigning two variables?

Comment: Anonymous ftp logins are usually the username 'anonymous' with the user's email address as the password. Some servers parse the password to ensure it looks like an email address. I don't know this FTPClient, but in apache example(given source link) it's clarification what to do when you want anonymous logging.